# What is the correct structure for using mocha to test your package?

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

Right now I have:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'parlay:synapsepay',
  version: '0.0.1',
  summary: 'synapse_pay_rest for Meteor',
  git: 'https://github.com/parlaywithme/meteor-synapsepay',
  documentation: 'README.md'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.0.2');
  api.use('coffeescript');
  api.addFiles('synapsepay.coffee');
});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('coffeescript');
  api.use('mike:mocha-package');
  api.use('parlay:synapsepay');
  api.addFiles('synapsepay-tests.coffee');
});
```

and

```
MochaWeb?.testOnly ->
  describe 'sanity', ->
    it 'is visible', ->
      chai.assert.isDefined SynapsePay
```

https://github.com/parlaywithme/meteor-synapsepay

I'm getting a `has no method 'testOnly'` error, running

```
meteor test-packages ./
```

inside `packages/meteor-synapsepay`:

```
ERROR: packages.json parsing error [ ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/me/parlay/packages/meteor-synapsepay/packages.json' ]
[[[[[ Tests ]]]]]                             

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20151018-00:24:58.123(-4)? (STDERR)          
W20151018-00:24:58.125(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.osr2yb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151018-00:24:58.125(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20151018-00:24:58.125(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20151018-00:24:58.125(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'testOnly'
W20151018-00:24:58.125(-4)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/local-test_parlay_synapsepay/synapsepay-tests.coffee:1:11)
W20151018-00:24:58.125(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/local-test_parlay_synapsepay/synapsepay-tests.coffee:1:1
W20151018-00:24:58.126(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/local-test_parlay_synapsepay/synapsepay-tests.coffee:1:1
W20151018-00:24:58.126(-4)? (STDERR)     at /private/tmp/meteor-test-run1tbmejw/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20151018-00:24:58.126(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20151018-00:24:58.126(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.osr2yb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20151018-00:24:58.126(-4)? (STDERR)     at /private/tmp/meteor-test-run1tbmejw/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While poorly documented at the moment, this issue can be solved easily:
Simply ditch `testOnly` and write your tests directly in your test file.

```
describe 'sanity', ->
  it 'is visible', ->
    chai.assert.isDefined SynapsePay
```

Mocha was first designed for application tests. Using it for package tests can prove challenging.
When you will have your tests running, you may also [see big `Meteor.methods` Match errors in the console](https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-mocha-web/issues/194). It is a common issue that should not interfere with the tests themselves.